# Use Python function call tips and method suggestions in VSC

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm trying VSC and love it so far, but it doesn't have any method suggestions some time.

Also, the function call tips are different from those found in Python's IDLE. It's just not that straightforward and I find it hard to understand as a beginner.
The comparisons between Python and VSC are as follows:

[image: Python method suggestion]

[image: VSC method suggestion]

[image: Python call tip]

[image: VSC call tip]

Are there any VSC extensions that could offer call tips and method suggestions like those found in Python?

PS: VSC extensions I already installed: Python, Pylance, Jupyter.

Comment: *Once you have a version of Python installed, activate it using the Python: Select Interpreter command. If VS Code doesn't automatically locate the interpreter you're looking for, refer to Environments - Manually specify an interpreter.* From [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python).

Comment: @Kevin M. Mansour I already activated the interpreter, which is Python 3.9.

Comment: You type, and you can trigger completions at any time with Ctrl+Space. You can also hover over identifiers for more information about them.